# Python loop speed comparison

Tags: python, performance, numpy, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I was doing an extremely simple coding exercise to compare the run-times with different approaches in Python.

> Task: Given a list of numbers, square and return each odd number in
>   the list.

```
import timeit
# 1. functional sol
s161 = '''seq = range(1,10)
result = map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x%2 !=0, seq))'''
u161= timeit.Timer(stmt=s161, setup='import numpy as np')
print u161.timeit(number = 10000)
>>>> 0.0283808019885

# 2. list comp sol!!! twice faster than map and filter
s162='''seq = range(1,10)
result2 = [j**2 for j in seq if j %2 != 0]
'''
u162= timeit.Timer(stmt=s162, setup='import numpy as np')
print u162.timeit(number = 10000)
>>>> 0.0124025493424

# 3. numpy sol (surprisingly the slowest
s163='''seq = np.array(range(1,10))
result3 =np.square(seq[seq%2 !=0])
'''
u163= timeit.Timer(stmt=s163, setup='import numpy as np')
print u163.timeit(number = 10000)
>>>> 0.0656246913131
```

So in terms of speed: List Comprehension > Functional > Numpy Vectorized. I would have expected the numpy solution to be the fastest and the functional solution and the list comprehension to come head to head. I am not really calling np.append(), but applying a vectorized operation.

Is the anlaysis above valid? If so, could you provide some insight as to why list comprehension is the fastest, and the numpy solution is comparatively very slow?

**UPDATE:**

Per the comments, for seq=range(10000), the comparison changes to:

```
1. Functional = 1.87310951806
2. List Comprehension = 0.941395220259
3. Numpy = 0.670276152436
```

Numpy fastest as expected. I am not sure why list comprehension is much faster than map/filter though.

Comment: The list comprehension is faster because you don't need to call any user-defined functions. I don't know why `numpy` is slower; possible because there is too much overhead compared to the small size of the array involved.

Comment: have you tested with larger lists?

Comment: At my end, with `100,000` as the length of input arrays/lists, NumPy is **`5x+`** faster than list comprehension.

Comment: Yes fair point, and I have not actually tested with a larger array. Will do this and update when I'm next to the computer.

Comment: If you want to see what's going on under the hood, look at the `dis` module: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html

Comment: Also test by removing the array (or list) creation from the timing loop.  The `np.array([...])` step has a lot of overhead.